# How can i link my layout to my assets on resources/views/?

Tags: css, laravel, view, public

how can I link the html layout Resources/views/layouts/color1 to the css in /Resources/views/color1/css/file.css?

Comment: **Note**: `$colors as $colors` is rewriting your `$colors` variable. So after your `foreach` statement has no more rows, `$colors` will be overwritten to the last colour in the collection (since it doesn't have its own scope). This only matters if you want to reuse your colours array in the future but just something to think about for 'best practice'. This comment references [before the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54277758/1)

Answer (score 0):

**CONTROLLER FUNCTION**

```
$colors= DB::table('colors')->get();
 foreach($colors as $colors) {
    $bgcolor= $colors->bgcolor;
}
return view('index', compact('bgcolor'));
```

**BLADE FILE**

```
<body style="background-color: {{ $bgcolor }}">
```

Comment: yes, i know the problem is link layout to css and js files hosted con resources path, if i host them on public path i can `<link href="{{ asset('css/file.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">` but which is the route to resources/views?